# How to spy on a function used in another function?

Tags: typescript, testing, mocking, jestjs, stub

I have a file containing source code `foo.ts` and a test file called `foo.test.ts`

```
foo.ts
```

```
function bar(argument: arg): boolean {
  return true
}

async function foo(argument: arg) {
  if (bar(argument)) {
    await promiseRequest()
  }
}
```

I am trying to stub `bar()` in such a way that when `foo(argument)` is called that `bar()` returns false.

I went through the [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) and tried implementing based on the methods there however they do not work when I call `foo(argument)` in the `foo.test.ts` file.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dependency injection for this.

```
foo.ts
```

```
function bar(argument: arg): boolean {
  return true
}
    
async function foo(argument, bar = bar) {
  if (bar(argument)) {
    await promiseRequest()
  }
}

export const Foo = {
  bar,
  foo
}
```

Then in your test file you can mock/stub `bar()` the following way:

```
foo.test.ts
```

```
test('Test for foo()', () => {
  const mockBar = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(value)
  expect(Foo.foo(arg, mockBar)).toBe(expectation)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this for a function that is used in the same module it was defined, unless it's a method that can be spied on an object.

`foo` and `bar` need to be tested together, or they should be split to different modules and mocked with `jest.mock`.